# C++ functor compile error

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have the following main program, which when compiled gives this error:
Undefined symbols for double squarer(double, SineFunctor&)
Why can't the linker find the function squarer?

```
include <iostream>
#include "SineFunctor.h"
#include "squarer.h"
int main()
{
    const double PI = 3.141592L;
    double x = 1.0;
    double y;
    //  initialize function parameters
    SineFunctor sine(2., 10.*PI, 0.);    
    // pass functions sine to function squarer
    y = squarer(x, sine);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the files for SineFunctor

```
//  SineFunctor.h
#ifndef __functor_example__SineFunctor__
#define __functor_example__SineFunctor__

#include <iostream>
class SineFunctor {    
public:
//  constructor to set function parameters
SineFunctor(const double amp, const double freq, const double phase);

//  function evaluation using overloaded operator()
double operator() (const double t);
private:
    double _amp;
    double _freq;
    double _phase;
};
#endif /* defined(__functor_example__SineFunctor__) */

//  SineFunctor.cpp
#include <cmath>
#include "SineFunctor.h"

//  constructor to set function parameters
SineFunctor::SineFunctor(const double amp, const double freq, const double phase) {
    _amp = amp;
    _freq = freq;
    _phase = phase;
}
//  function evaluation using overloaded operator()
double SineFunctor::operator() (const double t) {
    return _amp * sin(_freq * t + _phase);
}
```

and squarer>

```
//  squarer.h
#ifndef __functor_example__squarer__
#define __functor_example__squarer__

#include <iostream>
template <class F>
double squarer(const double x, F& func);

#endif /* defined(__functor_example__squarer__) */

//  squarer.cpp
#include "squarer.h"

template <class F>
double squarer(const double x, F& func) {
    double y = func(x);
    return y * y;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template functions either need to be in the header or be instantiated for all types in the cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Template definitions must be given in the header file because the compiler needs to know exactly what it should be instantiating. Move the definition of `squarer` into the header file:

```
// squarer.h
#ifndef functor_example__squarer
#define functor_example__squarer

template <class F>
double squarer(const double x, F& func) {
    double y = func(x);
    return y * y;
}

#endif
```

Notice that I've removed the double underscores from your `#define`. Names with double underscores are reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Or be instantiated for all types in the compilation unit where they are defined.